# How to store the output after calling a function and utilizing it in the next run

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran the below code in interpreter and called the union function

`quick_find(10).union(3,4)`

output: `[0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

`quick_find(10).union(0,4)`

output: `[4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

When I call the union function for the second time the ouput list should be this
`[4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

But instead it is giving me `[4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` as  output. How can i get my desired output. Please suggest

```
class quick_find:

    def __init__(self,n):
        self.id = [number for number in xrange(n)]


    def union(self,x,y):
        j = 0
        elements = self.id
        for i in elements:
            if i == elements[x]:
                elements[j] = elements[y]
            j = j+1

        self.id = elements
        return elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually calling that `union()` method on a new instance every time:

A improved version of your code:

```
class Quick_find:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.id = range(n)    #just range() is enough

    def union(self,x,y):
        for i,elem in enumerate(self.id):    #use enumerate() for indexes
            if elem==x:
                self.id[i]=y

    def show(self):
        print self.id

q=Quick_find(10)       #create a instance
q.union(3,4)           #call union on that instance
q.union(0,4)           #call union on that instance
q.show()
```

**output:**

```
[4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: the answer worked for me ... thanks for the suggestions in the code @ashwini

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the list you are requesting by not assigning it to any "placeholder" object/variable. Do it like this and you keep your list in tact.

```
myInstance = quick_find(10)
print(myInstance.union(0,4))
print(myInstance.union(3,4))
```

What you are practically do now is;

```
myInstance = quick_find(10)
print(myInstance.union(0,4))

mySecondInstance = quick_find(10)
print(mySecondInstance.union(3,4))
```

..which, obviously, doesn't work the way you want ;)

Comment: Thanks Allendar understood the problem as well as the solution.